# Stream.map() requires second parameter to be ? extends R>

Tags: java, java-stream

Below is my method in which I am trying to effectively simulate the decipherment of a [Caesar shift](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caesar_cipher) cipher.

```
public static void decipherCaesarShift(String ciphertext) {
    String[] alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz".split("");
    String[] cipherletters = ciphertext.split("");

    for (int key = 1; key <= 26; key++) {
        System.out.println("Key: " + key);
        Arrays.asList(cipherletters).stream().map(n -> {
            int newPosition = Arrays.asList(alphabet).indexOf(n) + key;
            System.out.println("The new position of the letter " + n + " is " + newPosition);

        }).collect(Collectors.toSet());
    }
}
```

However,

```
Arrays.asList(cipherletters).stream().map
```

gives the following error:

> The method map(Function) in the type Stream is not applicable for the arguments (( n) -> {})

Why is this happening? I have seen countless examples where this second parameter is not required - that is, where the parameter list is `n ->`.

Comment: `map` takes function as parameter and function should return something . Right now you miss return statement inside your lambda used in `map`.

Comment: My apologie, I editied it because I didn't include my return statement

Comment: Instread of `ciphertext.split("")`, you could also get an `IntStream` with all characters from the string by calling `ciphertext.chars()`.

Comment: I actually have used a slightly different code from the one above. Since the question has already been answered, I didn’t bother editing my post

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<R> Stream<R> map(Function<? super T, ? extends R> mapper);
```

`T` is the element type of the current stream,
`R` is the element type of the new stream.

> I have seen countless examples where this second parameter is not required.

You either provide all generic parameters or end up with a compilation error. Often, these generic parameters are resolved by a compiler, so you don't need to write `.<String>map(o -> o.toString())` every time. You write `.map(o -> o.toString())` instead.

The problem here is the compiler couldn't resolve `R` because there was no return statement in the `Function` you provided.  To put it simply, your `Function` isn't correct.

```
Function<String, Integer> f = (String s) -> s.length();
```

A `Function` always takes a value, and it always returns a value.

```
Function<String, Integer> yourF = n -> {
    int newPosition = Arrays.asList(alphabet).indexOf(n) + key;
    System.out.println("The new position of the letter " + n + " is " + newPosition);

    return newPosition;
};
```

There is another problem with `key` which can't be used directly in the lambda since `key` is neither final nor effectively-final.

A simple workaround would be

```
for (int key = 1; key <= 26; key++) {
    final int k = key;
    Arrays.asList(cipherletters).stream().map(n -> {
        int newPosition = Arrays.asList(alphabet).indexOf(n) + k;
        System.out.println("The new position of the letter " + n + " is " + newPosition);

        return newPosition;
    }).collect(Collectors.toSet());
}
```

Comment: I need the for loop because I am simulating a Caesar Shift cipher by increasnig the number of letters each character is moved every time the for loop is executed.

Comment: @Marvin sure, you can keep whatever you want. I just didn't include the loop to save some space...

Comment: I realized there were a few things I need to change in my code, but this answer was the most helpful to help me solve the issue. Thanks!